# Unused easyJet Extra Luggage

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, refunds, easyjet

My wife paid extra money for sent luggage we ended up not using on two easyJet flights - one international (Luton to Tel Aviv) and one domestic (Edinburgh to London).

Is there any way to salvage any of the surcharge we've paid (even in terms of credit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately [**EasyJet does not refund unused baggage allowanc**](https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/booking-and-check-in/managing-your-booking#)e as per their Terms and Conditions (emphasis mine):

> ### Add hold luggage, sports equipment or increase your weight allowance
>
> You can add new hold luggage or sports equipment, or increase your weight allowance. Just log into Manage Bookings or our mobile App and select the 'Add hold luggage' option. You’ll need the email address and password used to make the original booking.
>
> **We’re unable to refund luggage allowance you’ve already bought.**

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is no way to salvage even a partial refund, a refund for credit or to use the allowance for a future flight :/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You can always try contacting EasyJet to negotiate something.

Comment: Negotiate isn't exactly the right word. "beg" seems more to the point, since they can refuse without repercussions and you can't do anything about it.